# Getting an Error with MSMQ Creation

Tags: windows-7, services, msmq

I installed MSMQ on my laptop running on Windows 7 Enterprise. I created a console app that creates a queue but gets an error `A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation`.

Am I missing anything after activating MSMQ on my machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951677/why-does-msmq-think-im-on-a-workgroup-computer)  and includes comments

Being part of a domain is a pre-cursor for installing MSMQ in AD-integrated mode. It doesn't guarantee MSMQ IS installed in AD-integrated mode. MSMQ will install in workgroup mode if:

```
AD integration was not selected as a setup option
AD integration was selected but failed to initialise; check event logs
```

Yes, the workgroup name is confusing in a domain member situation.

I checked the logs and found that MSMQ was detecting a previous MSMQ configuration conflicted with it working with AD. I had installed MSMQ, and later enabled the AD integration. I completely uninstalled MSMQ, and then reinstalled it with everything (AD integration included), and I stopped getting the error.

Your comment describes the answer that worked for me: not only did I have to add the extra MSMQ components, I had to uninstall MSMQ completely first to get it to work properly.

Deleting the MSMQ object in AD first should do to the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've been looking for the MSMQ object in AD for deleting but I don't have an AD directory on my Windows 7. Would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: No, it's okay. I was thinking there was something wrong with my installation that's why I asked here.